# How to do a viewstate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, viewstate, loadviewstate

I'm new to Javascript,

I'm using the Javascript to get the file name from the FileUpload,

Here with my screenshot.

[image]

and my code

```
  $('#Q1DocPath').change(function () {

                var path = $(this).val();

                if (path != '' && path != null) {
                    var q = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

                    $('#lblQ1Doc').html('<br/>' + '<p>' + q + '<a class="close"><font color="red">x</font><a>' + '</p>');

                }
            })
```

May I ask about How can I do it in ViewState? (Store and Load)

Comment: what do u want actually?

Comment: @NithinChandran after I refresh the lblQ1Doc still keep

Comment: you want to keep the value of the `q` variable even after refreshed? is that it?

Comment: @NithinChandran Yes

Comment: you got wat u wanted?

Answer (score 0):

> What I understood from comments is that, you need to persist the value
>   of `q` once it is assigned. Use localStorage to save the data, so that
>   you can access it until get cleared by the user

For setting the value
`localStorage.setItem('path',q)`

For getting the value
`localStorage.getItem('path')`